# Get to a dictionary format (by just saving non-zero values and indices) from a sparse matrixin in python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a sparse matrix imagine something like following :

```
 X=([1.5 0.0 0.0 71.9 0.0 0.0 0.0], 
    [0.0 10.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0], 
    [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 11.0])
```

is there any specific method already existed which can convert such matrix into the following file format(or matrix), where each row only contain **nonzero values** and their corresponding **indices** of rows in X:

Example

```
X1=( 0:1.5 3:71.9
     1:10 3:2
     6:11 )
```

my question is is there any existed way which can produce such dictionary out of a sparse matrix in python ?

Comment: Please, post your attempt?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because The OP didn't show any efforts to solve this problem.

Comment: What if the second row were all zeros? How would you expect your output to be formatted?

Comment: I do not have such cases in my dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html). It contains the data you are looking for in its `indptr`, `indices` and `data` attributes:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
X = sparse.csr_matrix([[1.5, 0.0, 0.0, 71.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
                      [0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
                      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0]])
for row in range(X.shape[0]):
    sl = slice(X.indptr[row], X.indptr[row+1])
    pairs = zip(X.indices[sl], X.data[sl])
    print(' '.join(['{}:{}'.format(idx, val) for idx, val in pairs]))
```

yields

```
0:1.5 3:71.9
1:10.0 3:2.0
6:11.0
```

Comment: thanks again :) what is the best way to store this dictionary in its current format ? because later I need to concatenate another list (target labels) with similar length to this dictionary!

Comment: Please start a new question with all the details. There is a lot that is
confusing here. For instance, what
[dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) are you
referring to? and how do you wish to concatenate it with [a
list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)? You have to
explain how you want to do that. The string `"0:1.5 3:71.9"` has some of the
syntax of a dict, `{0:1.5, 3:71.9}` but if we made it a dict, we would lose all
the information about which row it came from.

Comment: Moreover, if there are two or more nonzero entries *in the same column*, then
you would lose information about all but one of those entries (since they would
all share the same dict key). So it would be reassuring if you can guarantee
that no column has more than one non-zero entry.  And if you plan to
concatenate two sparse matrices, can you guarantee the same for the combined
sparse matrix?  So please start a new question and show an explicit example and
what the desired result should be.

Comment: thank you, you are right I think I mixed up consent of dictionary in my case but they are not the same, the point is that I need just values and indices in each row and there may be more than one non-zero values in a column but it is not working like dictionary and we are not supposed to change the value in that case,

Comment: by the way I have asked new question in this regard again if you may have time to also see the new question and you may find it not correct please let me know to edit it [linke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403642/concatenate-a-customized-format-of-a-sparse-matrix-x-with-a-target-array-y-in-py)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you a long way there:

```
X = np.array(
    [[1.5, 0.0, 0.0, 71.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
     [0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0]])

>>> zip(np.argwhere(X).tolist(), X[X != 0])
[([0, 0], 1.5),
 ([0, 3], 71.900000000000006),
 ([1, 1], 10.0),
 ([1, 3], 2.0),
 ([2, 6], 11.0)]
```

You can also use a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {(row, col): val 
     for row, data in enumerate(X) 
     for col, val in enumerate(data) 
     if val != 0} 
{(0, 0): 1.5,
 (0, 3): 71.900000000000006,
 (1, 1): 10.0,
 (1, 3): 2.0,
 (2, 6): 11.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a matrix of rows and columns, in my humble opinion, I think you need to mention the row and column of non-zero values for ease reference later, this can be done without importing any libraries:

```
>>> x
[[1.5, 0.0, 0.0, 71.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0]]
>>>
>>> l = []
>>>
>>> for i,subl in enumerate(x):
        for j, item in enumerate(subl):
            if item:
                l.append(([i,j],item))
>>> l
[([0, 0], 1.5), ([0, 3], 71.9), ([1, 1], 10.0), ([1, 3], 2.0), ([2, 6], 11.0)]
```