# concatenate a customized format of a sparse matrix X with a target array Y in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, matrix

I have a sparse matrix X and a target array Y (which length is equal to the rows of X), imagine something like following :

```
 X=([1.5 0.0 0.0 71.9 0.0 0.0 0.0], 
    [0.0 10.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0], 
    [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 11.0])

 y =[4,2,-6]
```

what I need is to first have new form of the sparse matrix where **each row** contain **nonzero values** and their corresponding **indices** of rows in X :

Example

```
X1=( 0:1.5 3:71.9
     1:10 3:2
     6:11 )
```

to do so I have already asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388730/get-to-a-dictionary-format-by-just-saving-non-zero-values-and-indices-from-a-s) (however I still don't know **how to store X1** there so that later I concatenate it with Y?) but second part of the question is to **concatenate X1 and Y** (number of rows in X1 is still equal to length of Y) and **store the final result**, the final result should be something like the following format:

```
  data:
       4 0:1.5 3:71.9
       2 1:10 3:2
      -6 6:11
       ...
```

what is the way to get from **X,Y** into the final **data** and store it in a text file in Python?

Comment: Thank you in fact it is not a non-standard format but it is a standard representations of text document for machine learning techniques, in fact it is something like : [target] [id]:[frequency/count] [id]:[frequency/count] … it is the very usual format used in SVMLight and many other techniques

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate like so:

```
data = [[a]+b for a, b in zip(Y, X1)]  
# data = [[a]+b for a, b in zip(Y, [':'.join([k,v]) for k,v in X1.items()])]
```

and write to file:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for row in data:
        f.write(' '.join(row))
```

Comment: thank you my first problem is how to store the X1 so that later I can concatenate it with Y, in my previous question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388730/get-to-a-dictionary-format-by-just-saving-non-zero-values-and-indices-from-a-s/36389055#36389055) there was an answer which point exactly to the requested format for X1 but I don't know how to store X1 in that format?